# Refresh/reload a Window Browser by name

Tags: javascript, browser, reload

I know i can reload a parent page with something like window.opener.location.reload();

but it's possibly refresh other window browser using the window name ?

Comment: What is the “window name”?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given the named window was opened by the current window. Passing a second argument to `window.open()` will open it in the given window.
Example:

```
const abc = window.open("https://example.com/", "name"); // names the new window "name"
// can also be declared via abc.name = "name"

window.open("https://example2.com/", "name");
```

See MDN Web Docs for [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)